# Django HStore: How to override a key-value model field's __getattr__ and __setattr__

Tags: python, django, json, postgresql, hstore

I've been getting my feet wet with using hstore in Django, through the [`django-hstore` module](https://github.com/jordanm/django-hstore).  A big advantage to using `hstore` is that it allows for key-values to be stored in a field while providing decent indexing in Postgresql.  A big disadvantage to `django-hstore` (and `hstore` in general) is that you can only store values as strings.

To overcome this, I thought it would be nice to override the model field (`hstore.DictionaryField`) so that any data entered in to the field is automatically encoded in JSON and any data retrieved is automatically decoded from JSON. I've attempted to do this by overriding the `__setattr__` method but this causes tons of errors (when all the properties of the field are being set). Any ideas of the right way to do this?

What I have so far (I've commented out the getter portions while focusing on the setter, but left it in to show what I had in mind):

```
import simplejson as json

from django.db import models
from django_hstore import hstore


def _unpack_json(value):
    try:
        value = json.loads(value)
    except TypeError:
        pass
    return value


class HStoreJsonDict(hstore.DictionaryField):

    @staticmethod
    def _load_json(value):
        try:
            value = json.dumps(value)
        except Exception as e:
            # Is this needed?
            print(value, e)
            pass
        return value

    # def __getattribute__(self, key):
    #     print('__getattribute__')
    #     value = super(HStoreJsonDict, self).__getattribute__(key)
    #     return _unpack_json(value)

    # def __getitem__(self, key):
    #     print('__getitem__')
    #     value = super(HStoreJsonDict, self).__getitem__(key)
    #     return _unpack_json(value)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        print('__setattr__', key, value)
        value = self._load_json(value)
        return super(HStoreJsonDict, self).__setattr__(key, value)

class TestModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    data = HStoreJsonDict(db_index=True)
    objects = hstore.HStoreManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.name, self.data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day, I found it easiest to fork the `django-hstore` module and to put serialization/deserialization in the `DictionaryField`'s `get_prep_value()` and `to_python()` methods ([see here for code](https://github.com/alukach/django-hstore/blob/b5e68e4443d3cc0e98995b0ee5d34f21947698f3/django_hstore/fields.py#L115-L125)).

For anyone else looking to manipulate data on entry-to/retrieval-from the database when using Django, I highly recommend checking Django's docs on [to_python()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-database-values-to-python-objects) and [get_prep_value()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.get_prep_value).